# Convert system output into a vector

Tags: r

In the following, I am attempting to take the output of the system function to create barplot of the number of connections to each of the virtual hosts, however, I am unsure of how to convert this output into a vector for use with the barplot:

```
visitors <- system("sudo awk '{print $1};' /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | head | awk '{print $1}'")

hosts <- system("sudo awk '{print $1};' /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log | sort | uniq | sort -rn | head")

barplot(hosts, visitors)
```

Visitors' output would be a set of numberical values while the hosts is supposed to be (and is output as) a text string.

I realize how hosts and visitors appears above would not work (given that they're, in my rudimentary understanding, not vectors), but that is more or less how I'd ultimately try to associate the output with the respective axis, if at all possible.

The output appears as expected (that is, a numerical value for visitors, and a set of strings for hosts_, but I am unsure of how to turn these values into a plottable vector. Is there a method of looping in each of the strings from the output of system? I'd imagine if looped within system, it would still be read as a single value and, thus, not plottable (as far as I can tell). I am new to R, so perhaps my understand of how barplot is supposed to work is misinformed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `intern = TRUE`, In my setting for example I have

```
head(system("ls", intern = TRUE))
[1] "Articles"    "Books"       "coucou.tex~" "Cpp"        
[5] "Desktop"     "Devel"
```

Just to complete my answer, I'll add an example with real number

```
write.table(cbind(1:10, 3:12), file = "file.txt", row.names = FALSE)
vect <- system("awk '{print $1};' file.txt | tail -10", intern = TRUE)
vect <- as.numeric(vect)
plot(vect)
```

The conversion step with `as.numeric` is crucial because the output is of class character

Comment: Thank you. I need to rework what I have a bit, but this seems to have done it.